# Is this selector valid?

Tags: jquery

Is this selector valid? and what $(this) refer to?

```js
$('div', $(this).parents('div'))
```

i just learn javascript and jquery, thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's valid. It's taking all of the parent divs of `this` and then finding all of the divs underneath them. Breaking it down:

```
var jq = $(this);                // Get a jQuery object for `this`
var parents = jq.parents('div'); // Find all of its parents that are divs
var divs = $('div', parents);    // Find all divs under those parent divs
```

The result is a jQuery object with matches for all of the divs that are descendants of the divs that are parents of `this`. More [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

Example: Let's assume that `this` initially refers to the `input` element `foo` below:

```
<div id='d1'>
    <div id='d2'>
        <input id='foo' type='button'>
        <div id='d3'>
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='d4'>
        <div id='d5'>
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`$(this).parents('div')` will match `d1` and `d2`. Then `$('div', parents)` will match:

- `d3`
- `d2` (beacuse in addition to being one of the parents, it's a child of `d1`)
- `d4`
- `d5`

Answer (score 0):

Actually:

```
$('div', $(this).parents('div'))
```

The **[jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)** (`jquery()` or `$()`) needs at least one parameter of selector and second optional one is for a context, in your example `$(this).parents('div')`.

So, above code is going to perform on `$(div)` which is inside the context `$(this).parents('div')`. However, this is not that much usual, it most cases, it looks like:

```
$('#element').click(function(){
    $('div', this).addClass('some class');
});
```

In the above case, `this` refers to `#element` and then adds class to `div` inside that.